# ¿Se puede crear en Java un objeto de una clase y una interfaz?

Tags: java, class, interface

Me explico, me han pasado un codigo que tengo que revisar y encontrar un error, el codigo ahora mismo es lo de menos, la cosa es que es Java y hace un año que no lo veo y no recuerdo ciertas cosas y he visto una cosa que me resulta rara pero no recuerdo si se podia hacer o no, os pongo un ejemplo, tengo lo siguiente:

```
public interface Cobro() {...}

public CobroImp() {...}
```

Puedo hacer ahora..?:

```
Cobro c = new CobroImp();
```

Tengo que hacerme algun cursillo de repaso de Java que hace mucho que no lo veo jajajajaj muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué IDE usas? Normalmente lo que no se puede hacer (los errores de compilación) se marcan en cuanto los escribes.

Comment: Como dice Pablo, lo mejor para programar en Java es que utilices un IDE como Eclipse, que te da pistas sobre todos estos fallos y además te explica el motivo de por qué tu código está mal e incluso te sugiere cómo solucionarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede instanciar un objeto de una clase, de una interfaz no. Se puede crear un objeto de una clase y "asignarlo" a una interfaz que implemente la clase, como el código que muestras.

Answer (score 0):

Si puedes hacer lo que quieres, pero no tal cual como lo tienes ahora mismo.
Tendrias que hacer un cambio:

```
public interface Cobro() {...}
public CobroImp() implements Cobro{...}
Cobro c = new CobroImp();
```

Tienes que hacer que CobroImp implemente los metodos que tiene Cobro. Asi cualquier instancia de CobroImp se puede almacenar en una variable de tipo Cobro.